# Hardware change with Windows

Tags: windows, hardware-failure, reinstall

I wanted to know why is it necessary to reinstall the operating system when a CPU or motherboard change is made. I once changed the CPU in a Windows 7 and it got detected automatically. However, this isn't always the case.

Can someone tell me why this happens? Is it because of drivers, license or both? AFAIK this doesn't happen on Linux.

Comment: It's not required if you do a Sysprep, or use a program to restore a disk image, that supports restoring to dissimilar hardware

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft wants to check that you're not trying to run a single licenced copy of Windows on two different PCs in order to [stop its operating system from being pirated](http://www.zdnet.com/article/to-fight-piracy-microsoft-tightens-msdn-and-technet-terms-again/).

You may be able to reinstall from the original media if you have it [according to this technet article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6b62fb94-fef1-464b-be9a-21a80cd1abac/activating-windows-10-msdn-after-motherboard-upgrade?forum=win10itprosetup)

As Linux is licenced via [GPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) it doesn't have such restrictions. If someone wants to copy Linux onto another machine the licence permits it.